# Unable to install dnsmasq on Raspberry PI3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, apt-get, dnsmasq

I'm trying to install dnsmasq on my Raspberry PI3, But with

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

The result is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dnsmasq : Depends: dnsmasq-base (>= 2.76-5+rpi1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried installing dnsmasq-base, with the following result

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dnsmasq-base : Depends: libnetfilter-conntrack3 but it is not installable
                Recommends: dns-root-data but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

WHere I'm wrong? Is there a different source to be added to apt-get?

As an info, I just did an apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple: uncommenting the first line of sources.list allowed me to install the package without any problem